# Subquery I cant Figure it out

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

So I'm stuck on a problem that I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to 
"Select the Description of the most common delivery type".
I execute it but I get no return. I even tried replacing the counts with the deliverytype ID's but even then I receive no output. what am I doing wrong ?

```
Select DeliveryTypeDescription 
from DeliveryType 
group by DeliveryTypeDescription 
having count(*) >ALL(
      Select count(*) 
      from   DeliveryType 
      group by   DeliveryTypeID)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL-Server?

Comment: Yes im using sql server 2014

Comment: `having count(*) >= ALL(`

Comment: @artm It is SQL-Server (T-SQL to be exact). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
Select Top 1 DeliveryTypeDescription
 From  DeliveryType 
 Group By DeliveryTypeDescription 
 Order By count(*) Desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any way of doing this using a sub query?

Comment: @KristianAbenojar - why do you want to use a subquery?

Comment: This is the best solution to the answer that has been asked.  There is no need for a subquery.  @KristianAbenojar . . . If you have a different question, then you should ask it as a *question*, after accepting this answer.

Comment: Will do but did title it "Sub query I Cant Figure Out"

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the Delivery type will be primary key so the count will never be more than 1?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DeliveryType') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DeliveryType
CREATE TABLE #DeliveryType (DeliveryTypeID INT,DeliveryType VARCHAR(20),DeliveryTypeDescription VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO #DeliveryType VALUES(101,'Home','Home Delivery'),(102,'Work','Work Delivery'),(103,'Ref','Deliver to Reference'),(104,'Pick','Pickup');

SELECT DeliveryTypeDescription FROM #DeliveryType GROUP BY DeliveryTypeDescription HAVING COUNT(*) > ALL (     SELECT COUNT(*)     FROM #DeliveryType    GROUP BY DeliveryTypeID);
```

and in that case,

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #DeliveryType
GROUP BY DeliveryTypeID
```

will return all 1,1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DeliveryTypeDescription 
from DeliveryType 
group by DeliveryTypeDescription 
having **count(*)** **>**ALL(
      **Select count(*)** 
      from   DeliveryType 
      group by   DeliveryTypeID)
```

You're retrieving all rows, right? So I think you have to use '>=' instead of '>'.

Comment: Ultimately I need the one row of the descriptions that is most commonly used. When I add the '>=' It will populate all the rows but not the row that holds the most used deliveryType

Comment: And if you try "having count(*)+1" ? The fact is that with just ">" operator it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out the way to solve this problem using a sub query. My issue in the first place was that I wasn't thinking about the relation of the most common delivery type that was being used by a customer. The relative table that had the foreign key was in a "Customer Paper table". Hence all I had to do was find the highest count of DeliverTypeID in the "CustomerPaper" table.

```
SELECT  DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeDescription FROM DeliveryType 
INNER JOIN CustomerPaper
ON DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeID = CustomerPaper.DeliveryTypeID
GROUP BY DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeDescription
HAVING COUNT(CustomerPaper.DeliveryTypeID) >=ALL
(SELECT COUNT(customerpaper.DeliveryTypeID) FROM CustomerPaper GROUP BY CustomerPaper.DeliveryTypeID)
```